# How do i Replace function from wordpress plugins?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am starting to study action and filter in wordpress. Lets say i wanna add DIV wrap to the output of printif at the bottom of code. Can i just copy all this code into my functions.php and edit some of its codes?

```
defined( 'YITH_WOOCOMPARE' ) || exit; // Exit if accessed directly.

if ( ! class_exists( 'YITH_Woocompare_Frontend' ) ) {
    /**
     * YITH Custom Login Frontend
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    class YITH_Woocompare_Frontend {
public function __construct() {

            // Add link or button in the products list.
            if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'yith_woocompare_compare_button_in_product_page', 'yes' ) ) {
                add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array( $this, 'add_compare_link' ), 35 );
            }
            if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'yith_woocompare_compare_button_in_products_list', 'no' ) ) {
                add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array( $this, 'add_compare_link' ), 20 );
            }
            return $this;
        }

public function add_compare_link( $product_id = false, $args = array() ) {
            extract( $args ); // phpcs:ignore

            if ( ! $product_id ) {
                global $product;
                $product_id = ! is_null( $product ) ? $product->get_id() : 0;
            }

            // Return if product doesn't exist.
            if ( empty( $product_id ) || apply_filters( 'yith_woocompare_remove_compare_link_by_cat', false, $product_id ) ) {
                return;
            }

            $is_button = ! isset( $button_or_link ) || ! $button_or_link ? get_option( 'yith_woocompare_is_button', 'button' ) : $button_or_link;

            if ( ! isset( $button_text ) || 'default' === $button_text ) {
                $button_text = get_option( 'yith_woocompare_button_text', __( 'Compare', 'yith-woocommerce-compare' ) );
                do_action( 'wpml_register_single_string', 'Plugins', 'plugin_yit_compare_button_text', $button_text );
                $button_text = apply_filters( 'wpml_translate_single_string', $button_text, 'Plugins', 'plugin_yit_compare_button_text' );
            }

            printf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" data-product_id="%d" rel="nofollow">%s</a>', $this->add_product_url( $product_id ), 'compare' . ( 'button' === $is_button ? ' button' : '' ), $product_id, $button_text ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a class with the same name in two locations is asking for trouble. You can either rename `YITH_Woocompare_Frontend` or just remove all of the class stuff and simplify down to regular PHP functions which is what I would recommend.

Comment: I have tried using hook and unhook function but no luck so far. I cant rename the function cus its part of plugin.

Comment: You asked “Can i just copy all this code into my functions.php and edit some of its codes” and my comment was related to that. If you copy that over you can rename everything except the tags for the hook. The class, if you keep it, must be renamed. The methods in the class, except `__construct` can also be renamed as long as the hook signatures get updated.